# how to load image in HTML like a sliding from left to right for iPad Website

Tags: javascript, css, ipad, html

I have web page for iPad with graphics i want that graphs on page should load like slide from left to right as we normally see in Presentation i have seen many tutorial but they have sliding shows like image gallery on next button but i want that when image loads it should slide from left to right .

Below is my HTML code

```
       <div id="container">
       <div id="index" class="root_panel">
        <div id="image"><a href="#page_one">    <img src="image/startbutton.png" />      

       </a>
       </div>
       </div>
        <div id="page_one" class="panel">
            <div class="main_heading">Overview</div>
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="stix"></li>
                    <li><a href="#page_one"><img src="image/overview_active.png" /></a> </li>
                    <li class="stix"></li>
                    <li><a href="#page_two"><img src="image/strategy.gif"/></a></li>
                    <li class="stix"></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="image/draxxin.gif"/></a></li> 
                    <li class="stix"></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="image/excede.gif"/></a></li>
                    <li class="stix"></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="image/results.gif"/></a></li>
                    <li class="stix"></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="image/reference.gif"/></a></li> 
                    <li class="stix"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="rightclass"><img src="image/pageone_image.png"/></div>  
            <div>
```

Comment: In which manner those graphs are getting displayed, if i load that html page in Mac Safari?

Comment: now they are just showing simple load as we have normay have any button or image

Answer (score 0):

You can load the image asynchronously then insert it into the dom within a container with a width of 0px and overflow:hidden. Then, animate the width of the container from left to right.

You need to remove the image tags, and put ids (like "page_one", "page_two", etc) on the a tags that contain them. The a tags also need to be display:block;

Using jQuery:

```
<div id="container" style="width:0px;overflow:hidden;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

      //function to handle our images
      function slideImage(container, imagePath){
           container = $(container);          
           var img = new Image();
           $(img).load( function() {
                container.animate({width:'100%'}, 500);
           })
           .attr('src', imagePath)
           .appendTo(container);
      }

      slideImage('#page_one', 'image/overview_active.png');
      slideImage('#page_two', 'image/strategy.png');
</script>
```

Comment: i have edited my code also in which i want to perform this action on div id rightClass can you tell me how to do this

Comment: i have tested your code in separate file but nothing happening

Comment: it's an example, you'd need to bring in jquery and change the markup, jquery selector, and image path.

Comment: can you help me out this i have edited above code i am new to development

Comment: Sure, no problem. I will update my post to be a little more practical rather than an example. Does the part about bringing in jquery make sense?

Comment: yes or can we do like place the div in marquee and marquee should stop moving when div ends not on the hole page

Comment: my div is right class my i remove the img src from div and assign like this